# Which std::vector constructor is used here?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I have pice of code (it comes from https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Setup/Validation_layers):

```
uint32_t glfwExtensionCount = 0;
const char** glfwExtensions;
glfwExtensions = glfwGetRequiredInstanceExtensions(&glfwExtensionCount);

std::vector<const char*> extensions(glfwExtensions, glfwExtensions + glfwExtensionCount); // which constructor is used here?
```

Everythings compiles and works, but I don't get what happen in vector constructor.

Comment: The one taking 2 iterators i believe (begin + end)

Comment: Why not using a debugger? Step and you are sitting on it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's

```
template< class InputIt >
vector( InputIt first, InputIt last,
        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

(#4 in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).
It constructs a vector from a range of input iterators.

C++ iterators were designed to be compatible with pointers, i.e. a pointer is a valid iterator.

Comment: thanks, of course its range constructor. I get it now.

Answer (score 3):

The above definition of vector uses the `range` constructor. The [signature](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) is

```
template <class InputIterator>
  vector (InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
          const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

eg:

```
int main() {
  int a[] = {1, 2, 3};
  vector<int> v(a + 1, a + 3);
  for (int x : v) {
    cout << x << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Build and run gives ([source](https://ideone.com/2U4QfM))

```
2
3
```

The iterator started with begin + 1 to the last position, which is why the first element is omitted from the vector construction.